# Print Barcode from ID database

Tags: php, barcode

After my last barcode question i'm back with another. This barcode script:http://www.shayanderson.com/php/php-barcode-generator-class-code-39.htm 
works fine with a static number, or static variable:

```
$reparationid = uniqid();

// include Barcode39 class 
include "Barcode39.php"; 

// set Barcode39 object 
$barcode = new Barcode39("$reparationid"); 

// display new barcode 
$barcode->draw();
```

Bu, i want the $reparationID out of the database, the last added entry.i tried this, and it works without barcode:

```
$reparationid = "SELECT reparationid FROM reparation ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $link->query($reparationid);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print($row ["reparationid"]);
    }
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

as asked, the reparationid is shown as number, so it works. Now i wanted to merge those 2 scripts, but that is the point where it goes wrong. It doesn't work at all.
I tried this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print($row ["reparatieid"]);

        // include Barcode39 class 
include "Barcode39.php"; 

       // set Barcode39 object 
$barcode = new Barcode39("$reparationid"); 

       // display new barcode 
$barcode->draw();

    }
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

There is a blue question mark, nothing more.. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Br,
Daan

Comment: print($row ["reparatieid"]); -- instead of this in the second, merged code, you could set value for $reparationid = $row ["reparationid"]

Comment: **Tip:** Don't `include` whilst in the `while` loop. Move it above the loop.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with your barcode generator. It's a simple php-syntax question. So maybe you want to take a step back and [read about variables](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.php).

Answer (score 1):

**Tip:** Don't `include` whilst in the `while` loop, move it above the loop.

Change your line to become;

```
$barcode = new Barcode39($row["reparationid"]);
```

`$reparationid` doesn't exist in the script you've given, and if it does; it doesn't have the value you fetched from the database. (It does have the value of your database query string though)

Comment: i tried that, thanks! But it still doesn't work. i am starting to think that it is the barcode class that is not working well, because without it, it works fine.
$reparationid = "SELECT reparationid FROM reparatie ORDER BY toegevoegd DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $link->query($reparationid);


include "Barcode39.php"; 


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print($row ["reparationid"]);
// set Barcode39 object 
$barcode = new Barcode39($row["reparationid"]);

// display new barcode 
$barcode->draw();
    }
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}